# C++ compiler used by Ideone

Tags: c++

Which compiler does Ideone use to compile C++ code?

I tried to quickly google around and seems it should be GCC, but no source is explicitly mentioned.

Comment: Ideone's FAQ page answers this with excellent detail. Please do some common-sense research rather than simply executing one poor Google search then giving up.

Comment: @closevoters: You need a tutorial on what the English words in those close reasons mean.

Comment: I did more than one quick google search, also note that google change search results based also on what you searched previously so what you see when you do a query is different from what I see when I do the same query

Comment: Our results will not differ wildly for any search on this topic. It's not like we're asking Google for the nearest Nando's... Next time forget Google and spend 30 seconds looking around the actual site in question.

Comment: it is likely to vary a lot on not important topics. Search results are more stable for important topics only. Also sometimes I suspect certain pages are showed randomly when there's no reason to prefer one or the other

Comment: Sorry but that's nonsense. Are you saying that, for you, the first result for _"ideone c++ gcc"_ is _not_ the credits page, yet another source on that site (three, for anyone counting) that provides the information you need? If you didn't use that search term then it is your Google fu that has failed, not Google. :)

Comment: your query assumes you already know the answer is "gcc", wich is a bit unsensed since theorically when you make query you search for something you don't know. SO warns me to move conversation to chat ^^

Comment: Eh? No... You Google for keywords you expect to find in a result, so you'd first try "ideone c++ gcc" and then, if nothing came up, try "ideone c++ msvs" or "ideone c++ clang". Common sense really. You can't plug in "ok google what c++ compiler does ideone use please?" and expect to get your answer. I would also like to point out that, according to your question, you _did_ find out that the compiler were probably a GCC compiler, but for whatever reason you didn't use that discovery to finish your research with a quick, final query. So your assertion "you don't know [that it's GCC]" is false.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

it is gcc-4.8.1

[image]

From [ideone faq page](http://ideone.com/faq)

```
The following programming languages are supported:
name    version id (for api)
Ada gnat-4.6    7
Assembler   nasm-2.10.01    13
Assembler   gcc-4.8.1   45
AWK (gawk)  gawk-3.1.6  104
AWK (mawk)  mawk-1.3.3  105
Bash    bash 4.0.35 28
bc  bc-1.06.95  110
Brainf**k   bff-1.0.3.1 12
C   gcc-4.8.1   11
C#  mono-2.8    27
C++ 4.3.2   gcc-4.3.2   41
C++ 4.8.1   gcc-4.8.1   1
C++11   gcc-4.8.1   44
C99 strict  gcc-4.8.1   34
CLIPS   clips 6.24  14
Clojure clojure 1.5.0-RC2   111
COBOL   open-cobol-1.0  118
COBOL 85    tinycobol-0.65.9    106
Common Lisp (clisp) clisp 2.47  32
D (dmd) dmd-2.042   102
Erlang  erl-5.7.3   36
F#  fsharp-2.0.0    124
Factor  factor-0.93 123
Falcon  falcon-0.9.6.6  125
Forth   gforth-0.7.0    107
Fortran gfortran-4.8    5
Go  1.0.3   114
Groovy  groovy-2.1.6    121
Haskell ghc-7.6.3   21
Icon    iconc 9.4.3 16
Intercal    c-intercal 28.0-r1  9
Java    sun-jdk-1.7.0_25    10
Java7   sun-jdk-1.7.0_10    55
JavaScript (rhino)  rhino-1.7R4 35
JavaScript (spidermonkey)   spidermonkey-1.7    112
Lua luac 5.1.4  26
Nemerle ncc 0.9.3   30
Nice    nicec 0.9.6 25
Nimrod  nimrod-0.8.8    122
Node.js 0.8.11  56
Objective-C gcc-4.5.1   43
Ocaml   ocamlopt 3.10.2 8
Octave  3.6.2   127
Oz  mozart-1.4.0    119
PARI/GP 2.5.1   57
Pascal (fpc)    fpc 2.6.2   22
Pascal (gpc)    gpc 20070904    2
Perl    perl 5.16.2 3
Perl 6  rakudo-2010.08  54
PHP php 5.4.4   29
Pike    pike 7.6.86 19
Prolog (gnu)    gprolog-1.3.1   108
Prolog (swi)    swipl 5.6.64    15
Python  python 2.7.3    4
Python 3    python-3.2.3    116
R   R-2.11.1    117
Ruby    ruby-1.9.3  17
Scala   scala-2.10.2    39
Scheme (guile)  guile 1.8.5 33
Smalltalk   gst 3.1 23
SQL sqlite3-3.7.3   40
Tcl tclsh 8.5.7 38
Text    text 6.10   62
Unlambda    unlambda-2.0.0  115
VB.NET  mono-2.4.2.3    101
Whitespace  wspace 0.3  6
```

Comment: Also, the version for every language is stated on the site's FAQ.

Comment: link? I don't found it

Answer (score 4):

When you select the language on the Ideone, a tooltip is shown about the exact version. For both C++ compilers (named C++ 4.8.1 and C++11) a tooltip containing `(gcc 4.8.1)` is shown.

There is also C++ 4.3.2 in the Others section of the list, which contains `(gcc 4.3.2)` in the tooltip.

Comment: Also, there is a table with all of this information, on the site's FAQ.

Answer (score 2):

After some investigation here it is (luckily the first attemp was the correct attempt):

```
#include <iostream>

#if defined(__GNUC__)
  #define COMPILER "GCC"
  #define VERSION __GNUC__
  #define MINOR __GNUC_MINOR__
#else
  #define COMPILER "try another"
  #define VERSION "unkown"
  #define MINOR  0
#endif

int main() {
  using namespace std;

  cout<<COMPILER<<" "<<VERSION<<"."<<MINOR<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

the output currently is:

```
Stdout: GCC 4.8
```